# Faster loading with webos Enyo application

Tags: javascript, enyo

`Platform and framework WEBOS ENYO 2`.4

When I package up my application and test it on the emulator, the minification process seems to break some of the files.

I routinely have to run `ares-package --no-minify ./Ameba-moonstone` in order to get it to work.

I also noticed that moonstone library is quite large and around 400 files are downloaded on initial load .

Can you guys suggest anything I could do to get my application to load faster ?

Comment: One known issue where minification of javascript code can "break" files is if you are missing semicolons after some statements. Try to make sure that you aren't missing any semicolons in your javascript code, and see if that works better.

Comment: If you can create a reproduction case where minification is breaking your build we can try to put together a fix or identify what the misbehavior is.  Contact me on the Enyo forum if you need to send files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minification process uses uglify-js to minify the sources.  You could create your own minification process using uglify-js or some other node module.  The source for the minification and concatenation steps is in the `enyo/tools` directory.  You can perhaps even do a better job minifying if you can identify moonstone modules you definitely don't need and leave them out of the build.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using uglifyjs-folder

Comment: Is there a way to omit certain files using the ares command line when minifying ?

Comment: I have JS file which contains $.ajax({}) calls and it breaks at that file .

Comment: I'm not certain whether you can exclude a file. You could add it to assets and it wouldn't be minified.  Can you share the file?  Have you tried running the file through jshint/jslint/eslint?

Comment: The assets folder where we keep our images ? I can give it another run through using jshint/jslint